# How the preposition "of" is used after the article?

Tags: grammar

I read a sentence in a passage

> "We have been taught to believe that our lives are better than the of those who came before use ideology of modern economics suggests that material progress has yielded enhanced satisfaction and well-being."

In the above sentence i saw 'the' before 'of' what is special grammar behind it. Can you explain me the grammar behind it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be based on a transcription error and one that others are unlikely to encounter in this exact form..

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a transcription error. The original passage is:

> We have been taught to believe that our lives are better than those who came before us. The ideology of modern economics suggests that material progress has yielded enhanced satisfaction and well-being.

From the [April 5 1992 New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/1992/04/05/books/note-with-pleasure.html).

StoneyB found another passage that is even closer. The only difference between this and the question is the omission of the word "lives."

> We have been taught to believe that our lives are better than the lives of those who came before us. The ideology of modern economics suggests that material progress has yielded enhanced satisfaction and well-being.

Comment: A slightly different text (an improvement, actually, on the original!) appears in about a dozen English texts on the internet: A text which occurs in about a dozen English tests on the internet is "We have been taught to believe that our lives are better than **the lives of** those who came before us. The ideology of modern economics suggests that material progress has yielded enhanced satisfaction and well-being." I think another version of this, perhaps a mistranscription, is probably OP's source.